Hi all, vba seems to be unable to find the sheet within the specified workbook
i am using the below codes to help open my workbook find a particular sheet within the workbook and copy and paste it inside another, but somehow the code ends with opening the workbook and they cant seem to find the exact sheet.
Below are my exact code:
Sub advancetesting2()
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    
    ' Define the full paths of the workbooks
    sourceWorkbookPath = "C:\Users\amber.teng\OneDrive - PETRONAS\Desktop\APM\20240514 GHSB_Portfolio Model_May 2024.xlsx"
    targetWorkbookPath = "C:\Users\amber.teng\OneDrive - PETRONAS\Desktop\Enterprise model H2.xlsm"
    
    ' Open the source workbook
    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(sourceWorkbookPath)
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Open the target workbook
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(targetWorkbookPath)
    On Error Resume Next
    
    ' Set references to the worksheets
    Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Sheets("Enterprise console")
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Sheets("H2 project list")
     If sourceSheet Is Nothing Or targetSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not find the specified sheets.", vbExclamation
        sourceWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        targetWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Exit Sub
    End If
 
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Copy all data from source named range to target named range
    On Error Resume Next
    targetSheet.Range("destination").Value = sourceSheet.Range("sourceproject").Value
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "Error during copy-paste operation. Ensure the named ranges 'sourceproject' and 'destination' exist.", vbExclamation
        sourceWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        targetWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
   
    ' Notify the user that the operation is complete
    MsgBox "Data has been successfully copied and pasted.", vbInformation
End Sub

I was hoping the code can help me to open my workbook from a specific location and copy from a particular sheet to paste on the other sheet in another workbook. But VBA cant seem to find my sheet.

Hi, You have a few too many On Error Resume Next to even debug the code. Remove all of them and run the code and tell us where it stops.

How can you be sure the problem isn't with opening the workbooks when you just ignore any problem you had opening them? You should probably first check to see if those files exist at all.

Copy Values

You could use helper functions to determine the existence of the paths, the worksheets, and the ranges.
It is assumed that the code is in a 3rd workbook.
Each helper function will alert the user to what went wrong. The succeeding line of code in the main (calling) procedure will redirect the code to the ProcExit label saving and closing the files appropriately.
The code was successful only if the WasSuccess boolean was set to True and you see the last message in the calling procedure meaning that the values were copied and the changes in the target workbook were saved.

Main
Sub AdvancedTesting()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Advanced Testing"
    
    Const ROOT_PATH As String = _
        "C:\Users\amber.teng\OneDrive - PETRONAS\Desktop\"
    'Const ROOT_PATH As String = _
        "C:\Test\" ' my test path
    Const SRC_SUBPATH As String = "APM\"
    Const SRC_FILE_NAME As String = _
        "20240514 GHSB_Portfolio Model_May 2024.xlsx"
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Enterprise console"
    Const SRC_RANGE_NAME As String = "sourceproject"
    
    Const TGT_SUBPATH As String = ""
    Const TGT_FILE_NAME As String = "Enterprise model H2.xlsm"
    Const TGT_SHEET_NAME As String = "H2 project list"
    Const TGT_RANGE_NAME As String = "destination"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim swb As Workbook, twb As Workbook, WasSuccess As Boolean
    
    If WasPathNotFound(ROOT_PATH) Then GoTo ProcExit
    
   ' Source
    
    Dim sFolderPath As String:
    If Len(SRC_SUBPATH) = 0 Then
        sFolderPath = ROOT_PATH
    Else
        sFolderPath = ROOT_PATH & SRC_SUBPATH
        If WasPathNotFound(sFolderPath) Then GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    Dim sFilePath As String: sFilePath = sFolderPath & SRC_FILE_NAME
    If WasFileNotFound(sFilePath) Then GoTo ProcExit
    
    Set swb = OpenRefWorkbook(sFilePath)
    If swb Is Nothing Then GoTo ProcExit
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = RefWorksheetByName(swb, SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    If sws Is Nothing Then GoTo ProcExit
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = RefRangeByName(sws, SRC_RANGE_NAME)
    If srg Is Nothing Then GoTo ProcExit
    
    ' Target
    
    Dim tFolderPath As String:
    If Len(TGT_SUBPATH) = 0 Then
        tFolderPath = ROOT_PATH
    Else
        tFolderPath = ROOT_PATH & TGT_SUBPATH
        If WasPathNotFound(tFolderPath) Then GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    
    Dim tFilePath As String: tFilePath = tFolderPath & TGT_FILE_NAME
    If WasFileNotFound(tFilePath) Then GoTo ProcExit
    
    Set twb = OpenRefWorkbook(tFilePath)
    If twb Is Nothing Then GoTo ProcExit
    
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = RefWorksheetByName(twb, TGT_SHEET_NAME)
    If tws Is Nothing Then GoTo ProcExit
    
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = RefRangeByName(tws, TGT_RANGE_NAME)
    If trg Is Nothing Then GoTo ProcExit

    ' Copy values.

    If Not WereValuesCopied(srg, trg) Then GoTo ProcExit
    
    WasSuccess = True
    
ProcExit:
    ' Save and close.

    If Not swb Is Nothing Then swb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    If Not twb Is Nothing Then twb.Close SaveChanges:=WasSuccess
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    If Not WasSuccess Then Exit Sub

    ' Inform.

    MsgBox "Values successfully copied.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub

Help
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a boolean indicating whether a path exists.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function WasPathNotFound(Path As String) As Boolean
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Was path not found?"
    If Len(Dir(Path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        WasPathNotFound = True
        MsgBox "The path """ & Path & """ was not found!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
    End If
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns a boolean indicating whether a file exists.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function WasFileNotFound(Path As String) As Boolean
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Was file not found?"
    If Len(Dir(Path)) = 0 Then
        WasFileNotFound = True
        MsgBox "The file """ & Path & """ was not found!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
    End If
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Opens a workbook and returns a reference to it.
' Remarks:      It is assumed that 'FilePath' is the path
'               to an existing Excel file.
'               If the file is open, or another file with the same name is open,
'               the reference to the workbook will not be created.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function OpenRefWorkbook(FilePath As String) As Workbook
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Open and Reference a Workbook"
    
    Dim fName As String: fName = Right( _
        FilePath, Len(FilePath) - InStrRev(FilePath, Application.PathSeparator))
    
    Dim wb As Workbook:
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wb = Workbooks(fName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If wb Is Nothing Then
        Set OpenRefWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    Else
        If StrComp(wb.FullName, FilePath, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "The workbook """ & fName & """ is already open!", _
                vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Else
            MsgBox "Another workbook named """ & fName _
                & """ is already open!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        End If
    End If

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to a worksheet by its name.
' Remarks:      If the worksheet doesn't exist,
'               the reference will not be created.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefWorksheetByName(wb As Workbook, WorksheetName As String) As Worksheet
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Reference a Worksheet By Its Name"
    On Error Resume Next
        Set RefWorksheetByName = wb.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If RefWorksheetByName Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no worksheet named """ & WorksheetName _
            & """ in workbook """ & wb.Name & """!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
    End If
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to a named range of a worksheet.
' Remarks:      If the range doesn't exist, the reference will not be created.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefRangeByName(ws As Worksheet, RangeName As String) As Range
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Reference a Range By Its Name"
    On Error Resume Next
        Set RefRangeByName = ws.Range(RangeName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If RefRangeByName Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no range named """ & RangeName _
            & """ in worksheet """ & ws.Name & """!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
    End If
End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Copies the values from one ('srg') to another ('trg')
'               same-sized single-area range, and returns a boolean indicating
'               whether is was successful.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function WereValuesCopied(srg As Range, trg As Range) As Boolean
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Were values copied?"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    'Err.Raise 13 ' just to test ClearError
    If srg.Rows.Count = trg.Rows.Count _
            And srg.Columns.Count = trg.Columns.Count Then
        trg.Value = srg.Value
        WereValuesCopied = True
    Else
        MsgBox "Did not copy values from """ & trg.Parent.Name & "!" _
            & trg.Address(0, 0) & """ to """ & srg.Parent.Name & "!" _
            & srg.Address(0, 0) _
            & """ because the ranges are not of the same size!", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
    End If
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Could not copy values from """ & trg.Parent.Name & "!" _
        & trg.Address(0, 0) & """ to """ & srg.Parent.Name & "!" _
        & srg.Address(0, 0) & """!" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

